# Vectorizing a Pandas dataframe for Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Say I have a dataframe in Pandas like the following:

```
> my_dataframe

col1   col2
A      foo
B      bar
C      something
A      foo
A      bar
B      foo
```

where rows represent instances, and columns input features (not showing the target label, but this would be for a classification task), i.e. I trying to build **X** out of `my_dataframe`.

How can I vectorize this efficiently using e.g. [`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) ?

Do I need to convert each and every entry in my DataFrame to a dictionary first? (that's the way it is done in the example in the link above). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 22):

First, I don't get where in your sample array are features, and where observations.

Second, `DictVectorizer` holds no data, and is only about transformation utility and metadata storage. After transformation it stores features names and mapping. It returns a numpy array, used for further computations. Numpy array (features matrix) size equals to `features count` x `number of observations`, with values equal to feature value for an observation. So if you know your observations and features, you can create this array any other way you like.

In case you expect sklearn do it for you, you don't have to reconstruct dict manually, as  it can be done with `to_dict` applied to transposed dataframe:

```
>>> df
  col1 col2
0    A  foo
1    B  bar
2    C  foo
3    A  bar
4    A  foo
5    B  bar
>>> df.T.to_dict().values()
[{'col2': 'foo', 'col1': 'A'}, {'col2': 'bar', 'col1': 'B'}, {'col2': 'foo', 'col1': 'C'}, {'col2': 'bar', 'col1': 'A'}, {'col2': 'foo', 'col1': 'A'}, {'col2': 'bar', 'col1': 'B'}]
```

---

Since scikit-learn 0.13.0 (Jan 3, 2014) there is a new parameter `'records'` for the [`to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method available, so now you can simple use this method without additional manipulations:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'], 'col2': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']})
>>> df
  col1 col2
0    A  foo
1    B  bar
2    C  foo
3    A  bar
4    A  foo
5    B  bar
>>> df.to_dict('records')
[{'col2': 'foo', 'col1': 'A'}, {'col2': 'bar', 'col1': 'B'}, {'col2': 'foo', 'col1': 'C'}, {'col2': 'bar', 'col1': 'A'}, {'col2': 'foo', 'col1': 'A'}, {'col2': 'bar', 'col1': 'B'}]
```

Comment: Each row is an **instance**, i.e. a sample or observation, and each column is a feature type. In the example above I have 6 samples and each sample is 2-dimensional, i.e. my feature matrix **X** would be (6,2) in size. The task is to **vectorize** each column in **X** since they hold text entries and cannot be fed directly into a classifier or regressor.

Comment: @user815423426 finally understood. you might want to follow Matt answer or use `to_dict` to get needed dict (see update)

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at `sklearn-pandas` which provides exactly what you're looking for. The corresponding Github repo is [here](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas).

Comment: Let's assume that I have 40 columns and I want to vectorize only a few columns and keep the rest of the columns in DataFrame so that I will be able to supply the resulting numpy matrix directly to scikit-learn. Is this possible in sklearn-pandas? I mean sklearn-pandas is nice but when I call mapper.transform(), it only gives me the converted columns, not all the columns along with the converted ones.

Comment: Simply `column_stack` the transformed features and the original features together. Something like: `np.column_stack([mapper.transform(train), train[['c1', 'c2', ...]].values])`, where `np` is `import numpy as np`

Comment: You can also use `None` as transformer in the sklearn `DataFrameMapper` for the columns you want to keep unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

You can definitely use `DictVectorizer`. Because `DictVectorizer` expects an iterable of `dict`-like objects, you could do the following:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer


class RowIterator(TransformerMixin):
    """ Prepare dataframe for DictVectorizer """
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return (row for _, row in X.iterrows())


vectorizer = make_pipeline(RowIterator(), DictVectorizer())

# now you can use vectorizer as you might expect, e.g.
vectorizer.fit_transform(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to build a design matrix from a pandas DataFrame containing categoricals (or simply strings) and the easiest way to do it is using [patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), a library that replicates and expands R formulas functionality.

Using your example, the conversion would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import patsy

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'], 
                      'col2':['foo', 'bar', 'something', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo']})

patsy.dmatrix('col1 + col2', data=my_df) # With added intercept
patsy.dmatrix('0 + col1 + col2', data=my_df) # Without added intercept
```

The resulting design matrices are just NumPy arrays with some extra information and can be directly used in scikit-learn.

Example result with intercept added:

```
DesignMatrix with shape (6, 5)
  Intercept  col1[T.B]  col1[T.C]  col2[T.foo]  col2[T.something]
          1          0          0            1                  0
          1          1          0            0                  0
          1          0          1            0                  1
          1          0          0            1                  0
          1          0          0            0                  0
          1          1          0            1                  0
  Terms:
    'Intercept' (column 0)
    'col1' (columns 1:3)
    'col2' (columns 3:5)
```

Note that patsy tried to avoid multicolinearity by incorporating the effects of `A` and `bar` into the intercept. That way, for example, the `col1[T.B]` predictor should be interpreted as the additional effect of `B` in relation to observations that are classified as `A`.